# DownloadMnager setDestinationUri() to external private cache dir

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions, android-download-manager, android-fileprovider

I've noticed a behavior confirmed also by [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/MnctqJs9Cy0):

seems like Android's `DownloadMnager.setDestinationUri()` method allowing from android 6 and above to specify destination within the **private external cache dir** without the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission:

```
    request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(new File(getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/filename.xxx")));
```

while calling this line cause to exception to be thrown indicating `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission is required, it works perfectly on devices running android 6 and above (confirmed on Nexus 5 running, Nexus 5X and HTC 10)

I would like to count on this behavior and not use the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE on android 6 and above, but since I do not see any documentation indicating this is really a new behavior I afraid to do so.

so My question is:

Is it really android behavior on post android 6 allowing to set destination to this kind of private storage without any permission?

Comment: In the documentation, I see, DownloadMnager.setDestinationUri() required "write external storage" permission, so maybe in your application you have already ask for the permission at runtime? Is it possible?

Comment: @ErikMinarini: no, the permission not been requested on runtime. for sure.

Comment: I've also met this behaviour